# Using Ubercart's Product Key module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I have recently discovered Drupal and I have been trying to learn how to use it. I have, however, run into a problem: **Ubercart.**

Ubercart is a Drupal module that allows you to sell and track products and has an add on that allows you to provide or sell product keys. I have found that this module is notoriously badly documented, but has a sample in the download that "Demonstrates how to extend the Ubercart Product Keys module."

And in that lies my problem, with my lack of experience in Drupal and Ubercart's bad documentation I haven't been able to find where this "sample" is available on my Drupal installation or where I can see it in action so I can understand how this module works.

The Ubercart module is available at: http://www.ubercart.org/
and the Product keys extension is available here: http://drupal.org/project/uc_product_keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was more my (lack of) experience in Drupal than anything else. For those of us who are in the same boat as me, here's my explanation:

Assuming the *uc_product_keys_sample* module is included in *the uc_product_keys module* -like Clive pointed out- the standard code will generate a product key for every order placed in ubercart **if payment has been received**.

That last part was what confused me, placing the order is not enough. You can go to *Administer->Store administration->Orders* and change the order status to **completed**. That should generate a key or assign a key (depending on the configuration of the key sequence you are using).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the uc_product_keys_sample module which is included in a folder within the root of the standard uc_product_keys module.

As for seeing it in action, it's an API only example so you'll need to review the code to find out what you need to do.